# Overlapping/sticking a background image to overlap the border of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a page which is structured into two main divs. One's a header which sits at the top of the page and there is one below it which is a container for the page content. The header can be seen in the code snippet below:

```html
<link href="http://www.spareskills.com/css/compiled/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body id="postajob">
<div class="header">
  <div class="background-images img1 animated fadeInUpBig"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="animated bounceInLeft">Post a job.</h2>
        <p>
          Find a job by filling out your application below. It really is easy.
          <br>
          <span class="hidden-xs">Explain the job you need and people with the right skills will be in touch</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The relevant SASS/CSS is listed below:

```css
#postajob {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  .header {
    background: $postajob_header_bg_color;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $postajob_header_border_color;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    h2 {
      margin-top: 110px;
      color: $postajob_header_text_color;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 34px;
      z-index: 100;
      text-align: center;
      @include max-sm {
        margin-top: 95px;
        font-size: 28px;
      }
    }
    p {
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 17px;
      color: $postajob_header_subtext_color;
      z-index: 100;
      text-align: center;
      @include max-sm {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }
    .background-images {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      &.img1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('../../images/flat-icons/svg/paper-airplane.svg');
        z-index: 3;
        @include min-md {
          background-size: 150px 150px;
          top: 150px;
          left: 80%;
        }
        @include max-md {
          background-size: 100px 100px;
          top: 180px;
          left: 85%;
        }
        @include max-sm {
          background-size: 40px 40px;
          top: 180px;
          left: 45%;
        }
        @include max-xs {
          background-size: 40px 40px;
          top: 180px;
          left: 45%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see by resizing the snippet how the image behaves relative to the header. However this is all from hard coding pixels into the stylesheet as you can see.

**My question is:** How can I get the image to stick the bottom of the header as in the first snippet (when it is full size) no matter what the resolution or the device?

Comment: Your question shouldn't include links to external stylesheets. Take the time to reduce your question to a minimum example, then include that in the snippet, so someone trying to help you can see all of the relevant code without having to wade through a huge stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need background images or the grid system. The Bootstrap docs correctly state that is something is always full width, then you don't need the grid system.

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/gomoca/1/

*https://jsbin.com/gomoca/1/edit?html,css,output*

**HTML:**

```
 <section class="primary-page-header text-center">
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Text Goes Here</p>
    <div class="page-header-img center-block">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
  </section><!-- /.primary-page-header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.primary-page-header {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 4px double #aaa;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
.primary-page-header p {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.primary-page-header h1 {
      font-size:24px;
}
.page-header-img img {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    padding:3px;
    background:#fff;
}
.page-header-img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}

@media (min-width:600px) { 
    .page-header-img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin-bottom: -50px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .page-header-img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: -75px;
    }
    .primary-page-header h1 {
      font-size:55px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good advice and that looks great. However the issue for me is that looks great for small screens but on larger devices I'd like the image to be pushed all the way to the right and I'd like the height of the header to not be influenced by the image. I've tried floating the div and the image and can't seem to recreate it

Comment: You wouldn't use floats for that. The .container has a clearfix. To take something out of the document flow, make it position absolute in and adjust at the min-width: https://jsbin.com/gomoca/2/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have set left: 85% for the max size. It should stay on bottom if you set it to 45% just like the other sizes

```
#postajob {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  .header {
    background: $postajob_header_bg_color;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $postajob_header_border_color;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    h2 {
      margin-top: 110px;
      color: $postajob_header_text_color;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 34px;
      z-index: 100;
      text-align: center;
      @include max-sm {
        margin-top: 95px;
        font-size: 28px;
      }
    }
    p {
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 17px;
      color: $postajob_header_subtext_color;
      z-index: 100;
      text-align: center;
      @include max-sm {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }
    .background-images {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      &.img1 {
        position: absolute;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url('../../images/flat-icons/svg/paper-airplane.svg');
        z-index: 3;
        @include min-md {
          background-size: 150px 150px;
          top: 150px;
          left: 80%; ----> Change this to 45%
        }
        @include max-md {
          background-size: 100px 100px;
          top: 180px;
          left: 85%; ----> Change this to 45%
        }
        @include max-sm {
          background-size: 40px 40px;
          top: 180px;
          left: 45%;
        }
        @include max-xs {
          background-size: 40px 40px;
          top: 180px;
          left: 45%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this across browsers, but here's a solution using background image and a "padding height" trick. The `@media` queries are used to control which image is displayed at your desired breakpoints, to allow you specify higher-resolution images as the background image gets bigger.

For centering along the container's width, we use the position/transform trick (absolutely position the element, set `left:50%`, then `translate` the element -50% of its own width.

```css
header {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: ' ';
  border: 1px solid #009;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

header::before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 10%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  header::before {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/80x80);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  header::before {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is a header with some content.
</header>
```